# Emailing Report - Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, automationstudio, sql

Is there a way to Email a Scheduled Report (created using SQL) in Marketing Cloud Automation Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a complex amount of data, or is it something you could display in the body of an email?

I have several reports that go out daily to my team summarizing activity on our various recent sends (both triggered and ad hoc).

I have automations that run daily to produce the data (query, query, query, etc., ui) and then I have emails that just read from those DEs and present right in the email.  No attachments necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This can be hacked with the following steps:

- Create a Data Extension with the Report Headers
- Write a query and to extract the information and place in the the DE from Step 1.
- Data Extract: Create A Data Extract Activity to extract the DE from Step 2 to a location on the SFMC FTP.
- Combine Steps 1-3 in an automation via Automation Studio.

**Important Considerations**

- Emphasis should be placed on the naming patterns in the data extract. Depending on the frequency at which the report is required, I would advise using file naming patterns that reflect this ( eg. %%DD%%%%MM%%YYYY%% %%HH%  - for hourly reports)
- The Reports (Extracted Data Extensions) will remain in the FTP for 30 days, after which they will be deleted. This is because the FTP is a temporary storage solution.

Comment: thanks @data_kid! i assume we can build the email functionality by writing a script to fetch the file from the FTP and send an email?