# Same-day email-specific reporting

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, automationstudio

Default send reports allow a date window of the previous full day. I need to be able to automate a report that pulls the deliverability of an email shortly after it sends. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use automation studio to populate a data extension with a query against the _click & _open system data views.  Then use the data extract activity.

Here's an existing reference:
[Emailing Report - Automation Studio](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153732/emailing-report-automation-studio)

Comment: This makes sense (although I think I would be using the _sent data view in this instances.

What I'm confused about is, since Job ID creation is dynamic, how can I have this data extension populate dynamically based on the day's email?

Comment: Are you looking to have an ongoing report at 5pm (for example) that only pulls emails that have occurred on that same day?    If so, your query can be `Job ID` agnostic and use a getDate function to pull from a current system time minus X number of hours.